# How to optimize a high-order objective function?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I have an objective function which I want to maximize.  Ordinarily, one would perform some sort of optimization process on the parameters of this objective function in order to find parameter assignments that maximize the value of the function.

The problem is that the parameter to my objective function is a function from one countable set to another countable set, and I am unaware of any method that addresses such a scenario.

How do I solve such an optimization problem?  Under what set of assumptions can it be solved?  Even just a pointer at relevant theory would be appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, my objective function $f : (A \to B) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function of $s : A \to B$, where $A$ and $B$ are both countable sets.  I want to choose $s$ so that it maximizes the value of $f (s)$.

Comment: Can you write the optimization problem out? It is unclear what you are looking for. Is the problem $\max_{x\in \{g_1, g_2,\dots\}} f(x)$? where $g_i$ is a function?

Comment: Zistack: are you referring to this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_optimization

Comment: @cvanaret I do believe that this is technically a discrete optimization problem, since the function I'm choosing maps from countable to countable.  Knowing this doesn't help much, because all of the discrete optimization theory I've seen talks about choosing parameters, not functions.

Comment: maybe you could reformulate the problem by introducing decision variables $z_i \in \{0, 1\}$, then let your objective function be $f(\sum_{i=1}^n z_i s_i)$ and add the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i = 1$.
I'm not an expert in discrete optimization, but that's how a lot of discrete problems are modeled.

Comment: First of all I agree with @cvanaret. Now the question whether you have a concrete problem to solve, or you're wondering about the technique in general? As discrete/combinatorial/integer programming is a very large domain, with some if not most problems being NP-Hard, and they can all fall under the model you described. Therefore there is no single way to solve them.